# Hosting a PWA in ionic with mysql database

Tags: ionic-framework, hosting, ionic4

I have a mobile application in ionic and have uploaded it in playstore. Now I want to host it in a website. How do i do that with ionic 4 and mysql?

I have tried visiting the ionic documentation about PWA but they are using firebase.

```
 ng add @angular/pwa
 ionic build --prod --service-worker
 ionic build --prod
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you not need Cordova use:

`npm run ionic:build --prod`

and copy all from the www folder to your Web Server
or if you need Cordova
then Use Browser Platform for websites.

`ionic cordova platform add browser`

`ionic cordova build browser --prod --release`

and copy all from the /platforms/browser/www folder to your Web Server