# I need to scan a QR code in ionic 4 pwa application

Tags: ionic4, qr-code, progressive-web-apps

I had tried with **cordova-plugin-qrscanner**

It worked in my browser when I run my application using `ionic serve`.

I took the build of my ionic Project using command
"`ionic build --prod`" and i am running my www folder using http-server
Then I couldn't scan my qr code.In console i am receiving an error saying -

> cannot read property enumeratedDevices of undefined

Comment: Try to Build This Way https://stackoverflow.com/a/57410728/5909026. also enable service-workers inside your index.html.

Answer (score 0):

Extremely simple implementation!

Please check that out:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYChA-rPgpI

I did it using Ionic 5(build for Browser) and Angular 9. I deploy a small demo using firebase hosting.

https://qr-code-scanner-etc-test.firebaseapp.com/home

Tip: if you are working with Ionic don't use the Ionic native Plugins(BarcodeScanner and qrscanner)

Answer (score -2):

You can use the BarcodeScanner Plugin to scan qrcode : [plugin docs here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner)
The integration is very simple to implement, you only have to follow the docs as it is. It will work fine in Android but you need to add the following to your config.xml to make it work in iOS.

```
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" />
<edit-config file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge" target="NSCameraUsageDescription">
    <string>To scan barcodes</string>
</edit-config>
```