# IONIC 4 project won´t load after build

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, build, ionic4

I ran `ionic build --prod` command an then I copied files from /www folder to Apache, but nothing shows up. I tried this with cordova build browser command and I get same result.

Have anyone idea, why this happend? This happend on the blank project aswell.

Errors in browsers console: https://prnt.sc/pfbnk7

Files in www dir: https://prnt.sc/pfbnwu

Angular version: **8.1.2**

Ionic version: **4.7.1**

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57410728/5909026

Comment: check the path in the network tab where its trying to fetch the files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you copying files for?

## If you just want to run your app in the browser

The normal way is to run `ionic serve` and it will build + start its own server for you to test on.

## If you want to deploy as a web app

If you want to deploy this to a live web server, as a web app, then you need to do the steps below.

First off, be sure you aren't relying on any Cordova plugins as they won't work in the browser.

After that, you do this:

1. `ionic cordova platform add browser`
2. `ionic build --prod`
3. then copy the www in `platforms\browser\www` to the webserver

This is just a basic deploy.

## If you want to make a PWA

There are tutorials for making the app a PWA (which means it can be installed via the browser as an app on your device home screen).

You can either use Firebase Hosting, in which case there are instructions on the ionic docs website.

Or you can deploy it yourself which means adding the angular pwa package and some other steps I think. I can help you look this up if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yea, but this still doesnt work. I still have same error when I copy the files from platforms/browser/www to apache htdocs...

Comment: This is the correct way to deploy it so the next step is looking in the dev tools console for errors, and confirming that you aren't relying on any cordova plugins which aren't available in the browser.

Comment: actually I would test creating your own test js file in a known location and seeing if you can access it. It's possible your apache server isn't setup how you expect? Is it one that you have set up locally?

Comment: Yea, everything seems fine in xampp apache... I also tried this on some web hosting, but same result...

Comment: btw, how can I check if my app doesnt rely on any cordova plugin?

Comment: cordova handles it quite gracefully, you will see errors in the console log saying cordova isnt available if you are trying to use it. The splashscreen for example normally fires an error message off with all ionic apps but its only seen in the console.

Comment: so if you try to access the url of the js file directly is it working?

Comment: Here is screenshot of errors.. https://snipboard.io/PZo1Ss.jpg

Comment: When I try to acces url directly - http://localhost/main-es2015.dca06c244a3f43dca3dd.js, there is an 404 error

Comment: sounds like this is a server issue then not an ionic problem - perhaps file permissions or mime types but I haven't set up a http server from scratch for years so not sure on details

Comment: Probably... well, its wierd anyway. Thanks for your time.