# Ionic application not working after build

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, web-deployment

My Ionic V5 application is working fine for `ionic serve`

When I build the app using `ionic build` command, compiled js files, other assets files and index.html are generated to `/www` directory.

If I open `/www/index.html` file, a white blank page is open with some console errors.

Console error

[image]

```
Ionic:
   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.4 (C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.7.4
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.801.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.1.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

System:
   NodeJS : v12.6.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.9.0
   OS     : Windows 10
```

What went wrong here? Help needed

Comment: can you share Steps how are you making Build? also tell are you making web(browser based app)?

Comment: Also check my answer to this Question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57410728/5909026

Comment: build the application using `ionic build` command. And it's browser based application

Answer (score 0):

It's a path issue. Browser not able to find the all file that showing in error.
Just host the inside file of www on **server** and check.
You can not check directly just simple click on **index.html** file