# ionic / Angular Universal Serve SSR Error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I tried to run the angular universal serve on a ionic/angular Project. This Project is actually only a PWA not a Hybrid Solution. So I've try to build the pwa with ssr - that works. But when I try to serve the ssr I got some errors.
After I run the server the page is available on http://localhost:4000.

When I first open the URL I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: self is not defined
at Object.QdDj (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/s7development/s7angular/dist/server/dom-js.js:44:9)
at __webpack_require__ (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/s7development/s7angular/dist/server/main.js:26:30)
at __webpack_require__.t (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/s7development/s7angular/dist/server/main.js:83:33)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/s7development/s7angular/dist/server.js:553:26)
at Object.onInvoke (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/s7development/s7angular/dist/server/main.js:83544:33)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/s7development/s7angular/dist/server.js:552:52)
at Zone.run (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/s7development/s7angular/dist/server.js:312:43)
at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/s7development/s7angular/dist/server.js:1072:34
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/s7development/s7angular/dist/server.js:585:31)
at Object.onInvokeTask (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/s7development/s7angular/dist/server/main.js:83525:33)
```

When I refresh the page once, the following:

```
TypeError: _this.win.requestAnimationFrame is not a function
at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/s7development/s7angular/dist/server/css-shim-206ea950-3169f23e-js.js:573:27
at new ZoneAwarePromise (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/s7development/s7angular/dist/server.js:1093:29)
at CustomStyle.exports.modules.Pud/.CustomStyle.initShim (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/s7development/s7angular/dist/server/css-shim-206ea950-3169f23e-js.js:572:20)
at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/s7development/s7angular/dist/server/main.js:137828:38
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/s7development/s7angular/dist/server.js:553:26)
at Object.onInvoke (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/s7development/s7angular/dist/server/main.js:83544:33)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/s7development/s7angular/dist/server.js:552:52)
at Zone.run (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/s7development/s7angular/dist/server.js:312:43)
at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/s7development/s7angular/dist/server.js:1072:34
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/s7development/s7angular/dist/server.js:585:31)
```

and after that, the following all time:

```
TypeError: win.matchMedia is not a function
at Object.isPWA [as pwa] (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/s7development/s7angular/dist/server/main.js:90863:31)
at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/s7development/s7angular/dist/server/main.js:90817:89
at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
at detectPlatforms (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/s7development/s7angular/dist/server/main.js:90817:61)
at setupPlatforms (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/s7development/s7angular/dist/server/main.js:90812:43)
at global0 (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/s7development/s7angular/dist/server/main.js:139665:74)
at globals (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/s7development/s7angular/dist/server/main.js:139692:3)
at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/s7development/s7angular/dist/server/main.js:92236:39
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/s7development/s7angular/dist/server.js:553:26)
at Object.onInvoke (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/s7development/s7angular/dist/server/main.js:83544:33
```

My ionic/angular info:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.0.1
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.10
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.25
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3
   @angular/cli                  : 8.3.25
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   NodeJS : v12.15.0
   npm    : 6.13.4
```

Comment: Try this Method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57410728/5909026

Comment: but this only for a regular build without angular universal?