# Using barcode scanner for a PWA - Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, barcode-scanner

I am trying to create a PWA and use a barcode scanner. Is there anyway to use a barcode scanner plugin without using cordova? As it throws a cordova not available error on running it on a browser while using the ionic-native/barcode-scanner plugin

Ionic version - 5.0

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Plugin. If the plugin you want to use supports `browser` platform, you can use it on browser.
[Barcode Scanner Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner) supports browser platform. 
you have to change the way you build your project.

here is my Another answer on how you can make build for browser. 
[Check Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57410728/5909026)